# Change password with the use of a existing Salt

Tags: c#

I make a user and save this in an SQLite database. The user gets a password and a salt.

```
public bool SaveNewUser(string databaseFileName)
{
    bool faulted = true;
    string SQL = string.Empty;

    using (SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + databaseFileName))
    {
        var passwordSalt = EncryptDecryptUserData.GenerateSalt();
        var passwordHash = EncryptDecryptUserData.ComputeHash(Password, passwordSalt);
        var usereroleHash = EncryptDecryptUserData.ComputeHash(UserName + Role_Name, passwordSalt);  //to avoid copy role to an other user the combi username+rolenam ara saved

        if (Id == -1)  //-New User = 
        {
            SQL = "insert into QB_USER_LIST (GUID, USERNAME, PASSWORD, SALT, ROLE_NAME, GROUP_NAME, DATUM_AANGEMAAKT, AANGEMAAKT_DOOR, USER_ROLE ) ";
            SQL += "values (@GUID, @USERNAME, @PASSWORD, @SALT ,@ROLE_NAME,  @GROUP_NAME, @DATUM_AANGEMAAKT, @AANGEMAAKT_DOOR, @USER_ROLE  )";
        }
        else
        {
            //change existing user
            SQL = "UPDATE QB_USER_LIST set USERNAME = @USERNAME,";
        }
        m_dbConnection.Open();
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(SQL, m_dbConnection);
        command.Prepare();
        command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@USERNAME", UserName));

        if (Id == -1)
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@PASSWORD", Convert.ToBase64String(passwordHash)));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@SALT", Convert.ToBase64String(passwordSalt)));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@ROLE_NAME", Role_Name));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@GROUP_NAME", Group_Name));

            command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@DATUM_AANGEMAAKT", DateTime.Now));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@AANGEMAAKT_DOOR", Environment.UserName));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@GUID", Guid));
            command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@USER_ROLE", Convert.ToBase64String(usereroleHash)));
        }
        try
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Logging.WriteToLog("INFORMATIE", "De gegevens van een nieuwe gebruiker zijn opgeslagen. (Nieuwe gebruiker = "+ UserName + ")."); //AANGEPAST

            faulted = false;
        }
```

Then i want to change data from the user and use the same salt

```
string Salt = GetUserSalt(databaseFileName);  //This is "select salt from QB_USER_LIST"
var passwordSalt = Convert.FromBase64String(Salt);  //Get the excisting salt
var passwordHash = EncryptDecryptUserData.ComputeHash(Password, passwordSalt);  //create the new paspordhash with the same salt  --> goes wrong
```

I seems like i can't use the same salt again. I want to re use it because I use the salt to hash the field `UserRole`. Later when I want to change just the `UserRole` of a user I need to compare it with the salt.

Comment: What is going wrong? Do you have an error message? Is it going wrong in the `EncryptDecryptUserData.ComputeHash` method? If so, can you show the code?

Comment: Aside from whatever "goes wrong", it is not good practice to re-use salt.

Comment: Excuse me if I'm wrong but, if you use a SALT per client, isn't that meant to make it impossible to read the SALT again? That's like the whole usage of client sided SALTs... If you can easily use it again, what's the use??

Answer (score 0):

Found it. The password in my verifypassword function was not the password but the hashed password. So i was comparing 2 different things.